# Localization asset management

Tags: localization, resources

We have several large products we'd like to integrate with a consistent localization strategy.

We're already doing the right things from a code point of view - ie. strings in resource files.

I'm looking for something that will organize localized strings in a database, and generate the appropriate resource files (ie. .RESX files for .NET, .js files, etc.) during the build process.  Ideally, it would also be able to read in the files as well (detecting strings that have been added/removed).

The database would allow us to reuse translations in different products, switch to different technologies, and track what translations are missing in each release.

Has anyone found a good product that handles these requirements?  What have others done to manage localized assets?

Answer (score 1):

Found some good links in the answers for this question: [Do you know of a good program for editing/translating resource (.rc) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948/do-you-know-of-a-good-program-for-editing-translating-resource-rc-files/77807)

There's a number of products which we're now evaluating:

- http://www.lingobit.com/
- http://www.sisulizer.com/
- http://www.multilizer.com/
- WinTrans - http://www.schaudin.com/

None of have quite the database-based approach we were initially looking for, but they seem to have the core functionality.  Lingobit is an early favorite, but we haven't trialed in too much detail yet.  Does anyone have a recommendation between those products (or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [GlobalSight](http://www.globalsight.com/) or Alchemy's [Catalyst](http://www.alchemysoftware.ie/products/alchemy_catalyst.html)

Catalyst is a standalone translation memory and localization engine that can be used in your build process (and is used by many large software companies). GlobalSight is a relatively new and open source translation database and workflow tool that looks very promising.